# NSApplication orderFrontStandardAboutPanel: Making my about panel slightly less standard

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication

What are my options, if any, of adding additional, arbitrary data to the standard Cocoa about dialog that is displayed by an NSApplication when it receives a orderFrontStandardAboutPanel message.

Comment: You could wire the menu item to a custom action in -say- your app delegate and, from there, present your very own, fully customized window. You can read all the text info from your app's plist and obtain the icon image from `NSApp`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`NSApplication.AboutPanelOptionKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/aboutpaneloptionkey)

Comment: ah, I'm already using all of those options to show appropriate information for each dict key (pulled from the app bundle). The question is how can I show information in addition to all of that?

Comment: @Anthony either shoehorn your information into the Credits (or similar strategy) or make your own About window.

Answer (score 22):

If you add a file named `Credits.rtf` to `Resources` the contents will automatically be used in the expanded standard about panel and you can put whatever info you want in the file. It will still pull the standard copyright, version info, etc from the `info.plist`. It is the easiest way I know of to add arbitrary info, otherwise you pretty much will have to roll your own about panel.

Comment: If anyone (like me) just spend 10 seconds looking for that, now this group is called 'Supporting Files'...

Answer (score 7):

Expanding further on the answers from Darrell Root and theMikeSwan above, [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/aboutpaneloptionkey/2869609-credits) for the `credits` property of `NSApplication.AboutPanelOptionKey` states:-

> The value of this key is an NSAttributedString displayed in the info
>   area of the panel. If not specified, AppKit then looks for a file
>   named “Credits.html”, “Credits.rtf”, and “Credits.rtfd”, in that
>   order, in the bundle returned by the Bundle class method main. The
>   first file found is used. If none is found, the info area is left
>   blank.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on theMikeSwan's answer, by accident I found that if you add a file named Credits.html to the Resources folder, it's contents get used in the expanded standard about panel.  In fact Credits.html appears to override a Credits.rtf.

So your choice whether to use html or rtf format, or wire up "About" to a completely different custom window controller.